# Jquery syntax error while changing image src

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is my code to change the img src when one condition is satisfied

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
    var e = document.getElementById("shopperlanguage"); 
    var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

    if(strUser=="ja_JP"){
        var japaneseImgSrcs=['slider1.jpg','slider2.jpg','slider3.jpg','slider4.jpg'];
        jQuery(".jcarousel img").each(function(index,ele){
            jQuery(this).attr("src",japaneseImgSrcs[index]);
        });
    }
</script>
```

This code is not working and i'm getting syntax error in console on line 2.
I am not getting what is wrong with it?

Fixed the code as Beri suggested but still getting syntax error at line number 2 in mozila firefox console.

Comment: Can you post the full exact error you are getting? with line number.

Comment: Getting SyntaxError: syntax error at line number 2

Comment: Which line is line 2? Is this all of your js? What do you mean by not working?

Comment: It is not changing the image src url in slider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Wrong quote ending for slider2.jpg

   var JapaneseImgSrcs=['RevSlider_Ecommerce2.png','slider3.jpg','Zen-Den-Web-Design-San-Francisco-
    Home-Slider-1-1920x600.jpg','slider2.jpg'];
2. (Tip) Variable names should start with small letter.

Comment: But it is a good advice, sometimes it's good to tell it before someone will get used to it. Wrong naming variables makes the code harder to read.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can't put new line in your strings:

   ```
   'Zen-Den-Web-Design-San-Francisco-  
    Home-Slider-1-1920x600.jpg'
   ```

   should be

   ```
   'Zen-Den-Web-Design-San-Francisco-Home-Slider-1-1920x600.jpg'
   ```
2. Your last element has wrong quote:

   ```
   'slider2.jpg"
   ```

   should be

   ```
   'slider2.jpg'
   ```

---

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
    var e = document.getElementById("shopperlanguage"); 
    var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    if(strUser=="ja_JP"){
        var JapaneseImgSrcs=['RevSlider_Ecommerce2.png','slider3.jpg','Zen-Den-Web-Design-San-Francisco-Home-Slider-1-1920x600.jpg','slider2.jpg'];
        jQuery(".jcarousel img").each(function(index,ele){
            jQuery(this).attr("src",JapaneseImgSrcs[index]);
        });
    }
</script>
```